# Why is outlook/exchange de-formatting for bullet points in emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft

Person sends me a screenshot of outlook OWA email about to be sent, html is set, normal looking bullet point in the email.
I receive the email and the spacing is all off. Indentation is off. It looks like the email has been converted to plaintext.

Only happens with bullet points.

Comment: Does resizing the email viewing window change things? What about reading the email in a webmail/web view? If you copy the HTML code out and save it as an HTML file, and then open that in a browser, does it look like your Outlook client, or does it look correct?

Comment: Is your client Outlook set for Text Mode (one reason for this). Is the sender using a font (bullet and may text font) that you do not have on your machine (another reason).

Comment: I won't be of help with the why, only that Outlook OWA formats bullets differently than Outlook 365, and both format bullets differently than the Outlook apps. On top of that, the receiving email client matters, as it will modify the formatting of emails sent via Outlook (of any kind). This will likely be a better question posed on SpiceWork, where Microsoft employees actively monitor that forum daily during business hours to interact with users on technical questions like this. Modifying the default bullet indentations in Outlook screws up bullet formatting on multiple emails clients

Comment: Did you view it on the client or the web?